# Как правильно задать Stream API collect

Tags: java, java-stream

Допустим есть коллекция `collection` из объектов некоторого класса

```
class StringPair {
    String first;
    String second;
}
```

Я хочу получить `List<String>` из строк `first` определённого подмножества этой коллекции.
Для этого я пытаюсь сделать следующее:

```
List<String> result = collection.stream()
    .filter(как-то фильтруем)
    .collect(.......);
```

Что следует написать в collect?
Или предложите другие красивые способы решения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
class StringPair {
    String first;
    String second;

    public String getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public String getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
}
```

```java
List<String> result = collection.stream()
    .filter(как-то фильтруем)
    .map(StringPair::getFirst)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```